# Как реализовать таймер на сервере?

Tags: php, веб-сервер, mysql

Приветствую. Написал веб-приложение, загружающее с сервера вопрос. На javascript написал таймер. Т.е. за отведенное время пользователь должен успеть ответить на вопрос. Но клиентский таймер легко сломать и изменить время.
Поступил следующим образом. При загрузке вопроса с сервера, получаю функцией time() время в секундах и записываю его в БД. Пользователь отвечает на вопрос и отправляет ответ на сервер. На сервере снова функцией time() получаю время в секундах и сравниваю разницу со значением ранее сохраненным в БД.
Но если юзер успел ответить только на последней секунде, иногда возникает неточность времени и выдает ошибку. Как я заметил это происходит из-за нескольких одновременных запросов клиента. Т.е. я специально перед тем как отправить ответ, перезагрузил несколько страниц в других вкладках браузера. Из-за этого запрос запоздал. Не знаю что делать с этим, ничего не могу придумать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался.

Comment: Вообще вас не должно волновать то, что кто-то в других вкладках чего-то еще кроме теста пооткрывал. Если не успел значит так ему и надо. А вообще все очень просто надо получить время генерации страницы т.е. время работы вашего php скрипта и поставить относительно этого времени погрешность, еще желательно сделать запросы к тесту через ajax. Ну и сам скрипт максимально упростить. Если очень важно время чуть ли ни в долях секунды то надо очень четко понимать, что ширина канала интернет у каждого разная и получается, что страница возможно еще не успела загрузится, а время уже прошло.

Comment: а обязательно записывать время в бд? можно в cookie или в сессии

Comment: Да мне уже говорили, что лучше в сессии. Надо попробовать. Все запросы у меня и так асинхронные, без перезагрузки страницы. Про запросы в других вкладках, это я так, для примера сказал. Могут быть другие причины и источники запросов. Например программы обновлений. Но у меня выскакивает ошибка даже тогда, когда в браузере других запросов нет. Редко, но бывает выдает ошибку.  
Не совсем понял на счет времени работы скрипта. Как его получить и что это даст?

Comment: Я получаю значение time() и сохраняю его в переменную, в самом начале скрипта. Т.е. до обращения к базе данных.

Answer (score 2):

В базе/сессии (главное, что бы не у пользователя) запоминаете начальное время, а пользователю с помощью javascript показываете таймер. Когда таймер доходит до нуля, блокируете кнопку и не даете отправить. А вот когда пользователь отправил ответ, сверяетесь с базой. Если там на пару секунд просрочено - ничего страшного. Если больше чем на минуту - тревога. Конечно, время подбираете экспериментальным путем, возможно Вам нужно будет 5 секунд.

Таким образом, обычный пользователь видит обычный таймер, который работает адекватно. Для тех, кто захочет отправить ответ позже (либо обмануть), сработает серверная часть.

То есть, на клиенте интерфейсная часть, которая делает всю красоту, а на сервере проверяет, что все работает нормально.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверно так и сделаю. Блокировка кнопки у меня стоит. Блокируется когда закончится время, либо когда пользователь нажмет на нее. Просто некоторые в приступе эпилепсии любят нажимать несколько раз, чтобы наверняка, так сказать.)